# Play Http.Context implementation

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Does anyone know how Http.Context.current() is implemented? This is a static method, which I use in non-static method, in non-controller method, in non-single-thread application, and it works great. I am asking myself...how???

I am really curious how it works internally, because Play doesn't have one-thread-per-request model, and it is interesting how they did this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation you can see that current is held as a ThreadLocal value, so it is stored in the current thread:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Http.java

But how can it then be accessed in Futures which may run on other threads? There is a special execution context used called HttpExecutionContext which will capture the context so that it is available, you can see it here: 
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/libs/HttpExecution.java

If you would start using your own threadpool and do stuff on that though you may leak the context between threads and cause all kinds of strange problems.

Comment: Might be interesting to note that on the Scala side of play we do not do that but always pass the context as parameters everywhere instead (often with the help of a Scala feature called implicits)